# React Native StableID Collision when trying to insert pagination into flatlist data

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm trying to build an interface where I load data from an API and then insert pagination elements into the stack passed to a FlatList so that users can find their place easier (common complaint).

Right now I have it set up like this:

```
const Pagination = ({ index }: { index: number }) => <View><Text>Page {index}</Text></View>

const limit = 5
const [data, setData] = useState<(Item | typeof Pagination)[]>([])
const [paginationMeta, setPaginationMeta] = useState<{pages: number, perPage: number, page: number, total: number}>({})

const loadData = useCallback(() => {
  api.fetchData().then(({resp, metadata}) => {
    setData(resp.data)
    setPaginationMeta(metadata)
  })
}, [])

const paginatedData = useMemo(() => {
    let count = 1

    for (var i = 0, a = []; i < data.length; i++) {
      a.push(data[i])
      if ((i + 1 + limit) % limit === 0) {
        a.push(
          <Pagination key={`pagination-${count}`} index={count} />,
        )
        count++
        i++
        if (data[i]) a.push(data[i])
      }
    }
    return a
}, [data])

return <FlatList
  ...props
  data={data}
/>
```

When I run the program, I keep getting a StableID collision bug and it's causing weird behavior in the app.  My assumption here is that each time the `paginatedData` is recalculated, it tries to create a new element for the `<Pagination/>` that is already in memory?

ie this is happening:

Load page 1 - loop through data and create `<Pagination key="pagination-1"/>`
Load page 2 - loop through data and create `<Pagination key="pagination-1"/>` and `<Pagination key="pagination-2"/>`, but `<Pagination key="pagination-1"/>` already had been created in memory, causing the StableID bug?

Any ideas for getting around this?